# Linking radio buttons to data in Vue with render/createElement

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, radio-button, rendering

When creating radio buttons in Vue with the render/createElement function, how can you link the value of the selected radio button to the intended variable in the `data` object in the model?

Comment: [render-function.html#v-model](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#v-model)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it manually. See Vue's documentation on [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#v-model) on the render function page.

> There is no direct `v-model` counterpart in render functions - you
> will have to implement the logic yourself

Here is a really lose example that will emit the value of the clicked radio input.  You'll still need to solve ensuring that the emitted value is the actually selected radio as well as setting the selected value if that is designated as a prop.

```js
const foo = {
  props: ["name"],
  render(h) {
    const $this = this;
    const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
    return h("div", {}, arr.map(v => h("label", [h("input", {
      domProps: {
        type: "radio",
        name: this.name
      },
      on: {
        click() {
          $this.$emit("change", v);
        }
      }
    }), h("span", v)])));
  }
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      fizz: true
    };
  },
  components: {
    foo
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <foo name="some" @change="onChange"></foo>
</div>
```

Comment: $this.$emit() was used in the documentation as well. Is node.js required for this to work?